# SQL optimal query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

i have the following database structure:

[image]

And i have the task: select the buyer's name, Id of Order and book's name for orders that contains less than 3 books. I solved this task so:

```
SELECT b.Name, O.OrderId, bk.Name
FROM Orders O 
JOIN Buyers b ON b.Id = O.BuyerId
JOIN  BooksInOrder bo ON bo.OrderId = O.OrderId
JOIN Books bk ON bk.Id = bo.BookId
WHERE O.OrderId IN   
(
    SELECT OrderId
    FROM BooksInOrder 
    GROUP BY ORDERID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
```

Is my SQL the most optimal way to perform what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you try ctrl+L on your query?

Comment: How is it not optimal?  Have you looked at an explain plan?

Comment: @Andrew I think OP's question is really - "Is my SQL the most optimal way to perform what I am trying to achieve?"

Comment: @OverMind you are right - i just have some problems with English

Comment: @Junior222 It's understandable; no problem. I would edit your question and change your last sentence to something more meaningful. (You can copy what I said if you feel it is what you are seeking).

Comment: To expand on @YanireRomero's comment, `SQL Server 2014 - CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+L`, `SQL Server 2012 CTRL+L` (displays estimated execution plan). [This link may help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) in the long run.

Comment: In that case, you could look into using [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I think they will probably perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the only way to understand performance is to run queries on your system with your data.  Okay, there are some things that hurt performance (such as an unnecessary `select distinct` or `union` instead of `union all`).  Your query doesn't have those, however.

One obvious simplification is to move the `where` clause to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT b.Name, O.OrderId, bk.Name
FROM (SELECT OrderId
      FROM BooksInOrder 
      GROUP BY ORDERID
      HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
     ) o JOIN
     Buyers b
     ON b.Id = O.BuyerId JOIN
     BooksInOrder bo
     ON bo.OrderId = O.OrderId JOIN
     Books bk
     ON bk.Id = bo.BookId;
```

Do note that although this might look simpler, the performance may not be better.

Similarly, you could use window functions:

```
SELECT Name, OrderId, BookName
FROM (SELECT b.Name, O.OrderId, bk.Name as BookName, count(*) over (partition by orderid) as cnt
      FROM Orders O JOIN
           Buyers b
           ON b.Id = O.BuyerId JOIN
           BooksInOrder bo
           ON bo.OrderId = O.OrderId JOIN
           Books bk
           ON bk.Id = bo.BookId
      ) bb
WHERE cnt <= 3;
```

But your original formulation may still work best.

Comment: I'm merely asking out of curiosity; would a `CTE` be interpreted the same by the optimizer as the subquery, or would there be a variance in performance?

Comment: >the only way to understand performance is to run queries on your system with your data. 


Unfortunatelly my data is 5-20 rows in everyu table

Comment: @Junior222 . . . I would suggest you focus on learning different ways you can write the logic.  As you work with larger data sets, knowing different ways to get what you want will help you write better queries when it matters.